# RestFB jar added but FacebookClient symbol not found

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, netbeans, restfb

I have added RestFB .jar in my Netbeans.

However, they are still unable to identify the symbol of variable `FacebookClient`.

My code:

```
package fbapi1;

public class FBAPI1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String accessToken = "EAACEdEose0cBAHomDOKsugKsxT8XZB5IsIhtd77aA7L18Tpy0DIJNfbhsIjL9EcAOqyxZACOUxk52sw6ihZCZCUsMwBrtACFYQfNSE3fweh3jrYQss2nqGyXkWAhTCrCVZAQXoeE6cqquZC6eRnVcZB08N5YXmBSsEjNPXRndqHjE21U6lxWBwIBIXoNRZCvW";

    FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);

}
```

}

I downloaded the API from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.restfb/restfb/2.0.0-rc.1

Tutorial that I am following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwbO_PdwK_4&list=PLYPFxrXyK0BwiXNe09hTPjFqYbsWv8gxb&index=2

---

**Screenshots**:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: I tried reinstalling Netbeans but it did not work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the import. In Netbeans you can simply click on the red symbol left from the line and select "add import".

Please check this in the tutorial video at 2 min and 17 secs:
https://youtu.be/GwbO_PdwK_4?t=2m17s